# Scaling Implied Volatility by time to maturity

Tags: implied-volatility, term-structure

Reference request for any research that aims to "scale" the implied volatility by time to expiry so that the scaled IV data has minimal dependence on the time to expiry.

I tried removing the effects by running a linear regression of IV on tte and subtracting the slope*tte. I'd assume there would be better methods.

I don't prefer a complicated term structure model but any reference requests are welcome

Thanks.

Comment: Please comment what “focus” this needs?